# How to fix this shader to properly hide alpha pixels?

Tags: colors, glsl, shader

i’m working on a shader that basically creates a shadow cast effect for 2D images, almost everything works except when i try to change the color of the shadow, by default the color is black and the alpha pixels are hidden, but when i adjust the color (`modColor`) the alpha pixels become filled with bright color

[image: black]
[image: colored]

here is the shader code

vertex

```
uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

uniform vec4 modColor;

varying lowp vec4 vColor;
varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;
void main() {
  vColor = modColor;
  vTexCoord = texCoord;
  gl_Position = modelViewProjection * position;
}
```

fragment

```
precision highp float;
uniform lowp sampler2D texture;

varying lowp vec4 vColor;
varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform float shadowAlpha;
void main() {
  lowp vec4 bl = texture2D( texture, vTexCoord ) * vec4(0,0,0,1);
  lowp vec4 col = vec4(bl.rgb + vColor.rgb, bl.a * vColor.a);
  float useAlpha = shadowAlpha * col.a * (1.0 - vTexCoord.y);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(col.rgb, useAlpha);
}
```

Comment: how do you compute the color and alpha channel from the 1st image?

Comment: @Rabbid76 it’s the exact same shader code above for both, the difference is in the first image `modColor` which becomes `vColor` is vec4(0,0,0,1) and the second image is vec4(1,0,0,1)

Comment: What is the blending function and what is the alpha channel in the "non shadow" areas?

Comment: i’m sorry i don’t understand what you mean. i’m new to shaders. the alpha is 0, it’s a copy of the same image of the character.

Comment: In which environment do you use this shader?

Comment: it’s an iPad/iPhone application called Codea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the alpha channel of the texture (`bl.a`) is 0 in the areas without shadow and 1 in the areas with shadow, you can multiply the color channels of the fragment by `bl.a`:

<s>`gl_FragColor = vec4(col.rgb, useAlpha);`</s>

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(col.rgb * bl.a, useAlpha);
```